# Finding closest item in multivariate range

Tags: python, optimization, regression

Any direction where I can research would be great in itself, not sure if this can be solved using scikit, or numpy. I'm trying to solve an optimization problem where in a array containing X elements, return the item closest to the optimal ranges.

Optimal ranges: `[613.47, 45.235, 6.5, 36.39]`

```
[557.7000000000002, 46.67503968686453, 3.7847422859507507, 36.209384835209164] 
[559.9763265306124, 46.861468420280296, 3.792026948342387, 36.344933344740625] 
[562.2526530612248, 47.04789715369608, 3.799311610734023, 36.48048185427209]   
[564.5289795918369, 47.23432588711185, 3.806596273125658, 36.61603036380356]   
[566.8053061224491, 47.42075462052762, 3.813880935517294, 36.75157887333503]   
[569.0816326530613, 47.60718335394339, 3.8211655979089305, 36.88712738286649]  
[571.3579591836736, 47.793612087359165, 3.8284502603005652, 37.022675892397956]
[573.6342857142859, 47.98004082077494, 3.8357349226922013, 37.15822440192942]  
[575.9106122448982, 48.16646955419072, 3.8430195850838373, 37.29377291146089]  
[578.1869387755104, 48.35289828760649, 3.850304247475473, 37.42932142099235]   
[580.4632653061226, 48.53932702102226, 3.857588909867108, 37.56486993052383]   
[582.7395918367348, 48.72575575443804, 3.864873572258744, 37.70041844005529]   
[585.0159183673471, 48.91218448785381, 3.87215823465038, 37.835966949586755]   
[587.2922448979593, 49.09861322126958, 3.8794428970420154, 37.971515459118216] 
[589.5685714285715, 49.285041954685354, 3.8867275594336514, 38.107063968649676]
[591.8448979591839, 49.47147068810114, 3.894012221825287, 38.24261247818115]   
[594.1212244897961, 49.65789942151691, 3.9012968842169222, 38.37816098771262]  
[596.3975510204083, 49.84432815493268, 3.908581546608559, 38.513709497244086]  
[598.6738775510206, 50.03075688834845, 3.9158662090001943, 38.64925800677554]  
[600.9502040816327, 50.21718562176422, 3.92315087139183, 38.784806516307015]   
[603.226530612245, 50.40361435518, 3.9304355337834656, 38.92035502583848]
[605.5028571428572, 50.59004308859576, 3.9377201961751016, 39.05590353536994]
[607.7791836734694, 50.77647182201154, 3.9450048585667368, 39.19145204490142]
[610.0555102040819, 50.96290055542733, 3.9522895209583724, 39.327000554432885]
[612.3318367346941, 51.14932928884309, 3.9595741833500084, 39.46254906396434]
[614.6081632653063, 51.33575802225887, 3.9668588457416445, 39.59809757349581]
[616.8844897959184, 51.52218675567464, 3.9741435081332797, 39.733646083027274]
[619.1608163265307, 51.70861548909041, 3.9814281705249157, 39.86919459255874]
[621.4371428571429, 51.89504422250618, 3.988712832916551, 40.0047431020902]
[623.7134693877551, 52.08147295592197, 3.9959974953081865, 40.14029161162166]
[625.9897959183675, 52.267901689337734, 4.0032821576998225, 40.275840121153145]
[628.2661224489798, 52.45433042275351, 4.010566820091459, 40.411388630684606]
[630.542448979592, 52.64075915616929, 4.017851482483095, 40.54693714021608]
[632.8187755102042, 52.82718788958506, 4.02513614487473, 40.68248564974754]
[635.0951020408164, 53.01361662300082, 4.032420807266366, 40.818034159278994]
[637.3714285714287, 53.20004535641661, 4.039705469658001, 40.95358266881047]
[639.647755102041, 53.386474089832376, 4.046990132049637, 41.08913117834193]
[641.924081632653, 53.57290282324814, 4.054274794441273, 41.224679687873405]
[644.2004081632654, 53.75933155666391, 4.061559456832908, 41.360228197404865]
[646.4767346938777, 53.9457602900797, 4.068844119224544, 41.49577670693633]
[648.7530612244899, 54.13218902349547, 4.0761287816161795, 41.6313252164678]
[651.0293877551022, 54.31861775691124, 4.083413444007816, 41.76687372599926]
[653.3057142857144, 54.50504649032702, 4.090698106399452, 41.902422235530736]
[655.5820408163266, 54.691475223742785, 4.097982768791087, 42.037970745062196]
[657.8583673469388, 54.87790395715855, 4.105267431182723, 42.173519254593664]
[660.1346938775512, 55.064332690574346, 4.112552093574359, 42.30906776412514]
[662.4110204081635, 55.25076142399011, 4.119836755965994, 42.44461627365659]
[664.6873469387756, 55.43719015740588, 4.12712141835763, 42.58016478318806]
[666.963673469388, 55.62361889082166, 4.134406080749265, 42.71571329271953]
[669.2400000000002, 55.81004762423743, 4.141690743140901, 42.85126180225099]
```

The optimal output = 25th element.

Comment: Turns out the old answer wasn't quite good - you have 2 valid ones now - so duplicate retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the mean squared error (MSE) to measure the distance between your optimal range and your data:

```
>>> o
[613.47, 45.235, 6.5, 36.39]

>>> m
array([[557.7       ,  46.67503969,   3.78474229,  36.20938484],
       [559.97632653,  46.86146842,   3.79202695,  36.34493334],
       [562.25265306,  47.04789715,   3.79931161,  36.48048185],
       ...
       [664.68734694,  55.43719016,   4.12712142,  42.58016478],
       [666.96367347,  55.62361889,   4.13440608,  42.71571329],
       [669.24      ,  55.81004762,   4.14169074,  42.8512618 ]])
```

```
>>> np.square(np.subtract(o, m)).mean(axis=1).argmin()
24

>>> m[24]
array([612.33183673,  51.14932929,   3.95957418,  39.46254906])
```

Answer (score 1):

If by optimal you mean vector with closest Euclidean norm, this is a one liner with np.linalg.norm:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
       [557.7000000000002, 46.67503968686453, 3.7847422859507507, 36.209384835209164], 
...
[669.2400000000002, 55.81004762423743, 4.141690743140901, 42.85126180225099]
               ])

target = np.array([613.47, 45.235, 6.5, 36.39])



idx_thenorm = np.linalg.norm((arr-target),axis=1).argmin()

print (idx_thenorm, arr[idx_thenorm])
```

Result:

24 [612.33183673  51.14932929   3.95957418  39.46254906]